# Send An Email On Specific Date & TIme By ASP.Net and Using SMTP

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

Hi i have made application...that can have numbers of Event on Specified Date,
So i want to code tat when time for event is arrived so tat automatically the participant get information about the event..so i want to send email to all participant before a day..so suggest me the best idea of links

Thanks

(In Advance)

Answer (score 1):

Please look at Quartz.net, free library for doing scheduled activities.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Timer in the StartUp (or Start?) event handler of the Application class (Global.asax.cs).

Set the timer interval to e.g. one hour and check whether you have to send new notifications.

Edit: as Guffa responded already: this works only if the asp.net worker process is alive (e.g. when used in well frequented website)

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET application is not well suited for doing scheduled tasks. The IIS may close down the application at any time, and it may not start again until there is a request for the application.

You might want to use the scheduler in Windows instead to start an application regularly (e.g. once a minute) to check for events.

Comment: Guffa is correct. ASPNET is not meant for this. It's possible that the ASPNET app might not even be awake to send any emails when you need them to be sent.